# Can my Google+ contacts know in which circle I put them?

Tags: privacy, google-plus

Is there any way for my contacts to know whether I have put them in circle "Close friends" or "Annoying acquaintances" ?

In Facebook, groups can be public. I could not see that directly on Google+, but maybe some APIs have access to it? Or is it something that Google considers as a an important privacy point?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From Google's own page:

### [Who can see your circles](http://www.google.com/support/+/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=1257347&answer=1290507)

> When you place people into circles, or when you share with your
>   circles, **we won't disclose the titles of the circles people are
>   in**. People in circles that you share with may be able to see some of
>   the others with whom that content was also shared.

Answer (score 19):

The Circles feature works one-way, meaning that their members can't see if they are part of a Circle or not.

> But Circles are one-way, or asymmetric. Everyone sets up their own Circles and nobody knows whose Circle they are in. Secret Circles would be a more apt description. Zuckerberg seems to be suggesting that they are not really groups because instead of everyone in the group knowing who else is in the group, it is the exact opposite: nobody knows which groups they are in.

From here: http://techcrunch.com/2011/07/06/zuckerberg-dig-at-google-circles/

Comment: Just a clarification: They will know that you put that in a circle but not in which.

Comment: You can mark a Circle as private so that the people in that Circle aren't "outed". You can also hide all of the people in your Circles.

Comment: You can hide your circles from appearing on your profile page, yes; but you cannot add somebody to a circle and hide that from them.  I.e., there is no "stalking" mode.

Comment: If I put a contact in a Circle named Private can some one in the Circle named Friends SEE that I have the other acquaintance?