# Who can view which circles in Google Plus?

Tags: google-plus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can my Google+ contacts know in which circle I put them?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17029/can-my-google-contacts-know-in-which-circle-i-put-them)

Can members of one circle view members of other circles?
Is there anyway that members of a circle can view only the members of the circle in which they reside (for example members of family circle can view only my family circle members but not others)

Comment: How the hell this question is a duplicate? Both are totally different issues. One about if one can view in which circle he exist, while I asked if I can make them see only people of their circle *without telling them in which circle they exist*

Comment: Good point. I agree this shouldn't be marked as duplicate, but the duplicate should only be linked to. You should post in Meta http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/ to un-close this. Oh, and you may want to adjust the title to be more clear of the difference.

Comment: In general, no. Depending on your privacy settings, when looking at your profile people can see who is in your Circles. It's basically all or nothing; there's no check to see if the person viewing your profile is in one of your Circles and to limit them to only seeing other people you've placed in the same Circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not possible. Others can see only the people that are in all your circles. The circles are private to you. Nobody can see their names or the members.

Comment: They can't see the names of your circles. You can change privacy to show or not show who you have in circles. Users who have been shared a post can see other people who were also shared the same item, but that doesn't necessarily line up with exact circles since you can combine circles or list individuals. See the Duplicate answer linked to above (http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17029/can-my-google-contacts-know-in-which-circle-i-put-them) for a more extended Answer.